# How to get the name of the logged in user in My task dashlet

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

How to get the name of the logged in user so `My task` dashlet will read as `Username Task`. I tried `${person.properties.userName}` but I am getting error. My code snippet is

```
<#assign name = person.properties.userName>
 <div class="dashlet my-tasks">
 <div class="title"> ${name} Task </div>
```

But it is showing error

```
An error has occured in the Share component: /share/service/components/dashlets/my-tasks.
It responded with a status of 500 - Internal Error.
Error Code Information: 500 - An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request.
Error Message: 04120000 Failed to process template org/alfresco/components/dashlets/my-tasks.get.html.ftl
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Share is different from the repository with regards to root objects.

You have a variable `user` (of java type `org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptUser`) which has a method `getName()`.

To get the username in a freemarker template (in Share), you can use `${user.name}` or `${user.getName()}`